# split US phone number in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement as below. i have US phone number (10) digits and i need to extract areacode, prefix and number from it.

```
Ex: 1234567890
it should take 1234567890 and it should return 3 strings as below:

123
456
7890
```

How can i do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Accept an answer? I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

```
String areaCode = number.substring(0,3);
String prefix = number.substring(3,6);
String rest = number.substring(6);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter the 10-digit phone number, e.g. 1234567890");
String phoneNum = Integer.toString(keyboard.nextInt()); 

String first = phoneNum.substring(0,3);
String second = phoneNum.substring(3,6);
String third = phoneNum.substring(6);

System.out.println(first);
System.out.println(second);
System.out.println(third);

Run Output:

A prompt appears asking for this:
Please enter the 10-digit phone number, e.g. 1234567890

You enter (for example) 1234567890.

Method takes the substrings, and prints them on its own separate line.
Final Output: 

123
456
7890
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

String str = "1234567890";

```
    System.out.println(str.substring(0,3));
    System.out.println(str.substring(3,6));
    System.out.println(str.substring(6));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this pattern too:

```
(\d){3}(\d){3}(\d){4}$
```